# Formulario heredado (Windows Form) no funciona

Tags: windows-forms, vb, net

Trato de **heredar un formulario**. 
Cuando compilo mi proyecto **con x86 la herencia funciona bien**, pero cuando lo compilo a x64 se malogra el formulari. En tiempo de diseño ya no me muestra el formulario sino este mensaje diciendo que **la clase especificada no puede ser distinta de la clase base**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que puede ser un tema de referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio es una app de 32 bits. Windows no permite compartir entre 32-bits y 64-bits.

Como WPF designer es de 32-bits, los ensambles tiene que serlo también.

JMarsh plantea esta solución:

Diseña tu app con la opción "Any CPU/Cualquier CPU". De esta forma necesites depurar específicamente 64 bits, cambia tu configuración de compilación a 64 bits.

Basado en la solución aportada por JMarsh a esta pregunta en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378919/visual-studio-designer-in-x64-doesnt-work